# Read bits from Int16 value C#

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-or, bitwise-xor

In code below we can set specific bits in to an Int16 value:

```
short X = 1;
var bitsToSet = new[] { 5, 9 };
var result = X | bitsToSet.Aggregate((s, a) => s |= 1 << a);
```

I would like to read all bits from the short X and put them in an array or put each bit to a bool value, in a more efficient manner.

Comment: It can be done of course, but when programmers ask about this sort of thing it's usually an XY problem that can be solved much more easily with bitwise arithmetic instead of extracting all the bits and then doing something with the positions.

Comment: Yes, But I need each bit saved in to a specific boolean value.

Comment: Then just do that, an array with positions of set bits is useless to accomplish that

Comment: Imagine that you have 14 check boxes you could check or unchecked and you want to save the result in a short value X. You need to set bits individually as I showed above and retrieve them as well in specific values you could later analyse. Do you have a way to achieve the second part of the job?

Comment: You know how to set the bits, to test: `bool bitk = (theShort & (1 << k)) != 0`, just fill in `k` for every bit you want to test.

Comment: oh thanks. I just use a loop to test all. nice :)